# Messed up shed concrete pier foundation - wrong spacing. Does my plan to fix this look realistic?

Tags: concrete, foundation, shed

Hmm. So here's the situation. I've ordered a 10x16 shed and decided to build concrete piers foundation. Iv'e used shed manufacturer instructions but messed up the piers positioning.
As you can see I've positioned piers 2 feet away from the shed edge as opposed to 1 ft... (facepalm)

[image]

So in order to fix this I plan to use sistered 2x8s instead of 6x6 as suggested by the construction plan. Shed floor has five 4x4 runners which I think will help to distribute the weight ([see schematic here](https://imgur.com/a/l81uV)) and offset the fact that piers are further from the edge.

Do u guys think this will work?

Comment: How high above grade level will the shed be?   You could put blocking under the joists or skids.   It wouldn't tie into the ground, but it would still help support.

Answer (score 1):

Nvm. talked to couple of construction guys  that told me Ill be fine -> as long as I use sistered and glued together 2x8s. So I'll go with that.