# Shed 20x16 first time building

Tags: framing, structural, shed, lumber

I’m planning on building a 20x16 shed. I’m thinking on buying 12in x 48in Quikcrete tubes and placing 6x6x20 treated lumber on top. Will this work?

Comment: Have you checked the local frost level and if you need permits?  6x6 will probably need a tube for support after six feet, maybe up to ten feet, so at least three tubes per beam.  If in Quebec, four feet might not be long enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/101345/messed-up-shed-concrete-pier-foundation-wrong-spacing-does-my-plan-to-fix-thi

Comment: This isn't enough information. 6x6 beams are very inefficient. You want tall and skinny beams. What kind of snow loads do you get? A locality is probably easiest.